How to group several objects animations ? Like a precomp in Adobe Premiere, After effect or Level Sequence in Unreal
Context :

In Premiere Pro, you can select several video clips, hit Precompose and it creates a new clip, like a folder of the previously selected clips.
In Unreal, there is Level Sequence that do exactly this.

How can we achieve this in Blender ?
In details :

Animate 2 or more objects
Hit a precomp button to group their animations
Move this group anywhere on the timeline
Open the group and edit starting at frame 0

The NLA is not exactly suitable as the actions are for 1 object only.
If this is possible by using a workflow with the Scenes let me know.

This is a feature that's coming in 4.4: https://video.blender.org/w/ed5c5b62-7d7c-414e-ab43-64c87960a342

Thanks @Crantisz, it seems to be exactly this. I'll try it asap
Alpha version is already out, and release is supposed to be on march 2025. More info on dates here https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/milestone/24
